# Python3.x: TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not iterable & AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

when I try this,

```
archivist_dates=[
    "Thur,19th of October",
    "Fri,20th of October",
    "Sat,21th of October",
    "Sun,22th of October",
    "Mon,23th of October",
    "Tue,24th of October",
    "Wed,25th of October",
    "Latest"]# the list of dates to be selected by the users



variable=StringVar()
variable.set(archivist_dates[0])

list_menu=OptionMenu(archivist_gui,variable,*archivist_dates)
list_menu.grid(row=2,column=2)


archivist_buttons=Frame(archivist_gui)
extract_button=Radiobutton(archivist_buttons,variable,text='Extract news 
from archive', value=1, font=('Times',24),command=extracts)

display_button=Radiobutton(archivist_buttons,variable,text='Display news 
extracted',value=2,font=('Times',24),command=htmlgenerator)

archive_button=Radiobutton(archivist_buttons,variable,text='Archive the 
latest news',value=3,font=('Tikmes',24),command=download)
```

There was an error statement showed up as following:

> _cnfmerge: fallback due to: 'StringVar' object is not iterable Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py",
>   line 103, in _cnfmerge
>       cnf.update(c) TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not iterable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> >     "/Volumes/study/en01/ifb104/ass2/InternetArchive/news_archivist.py",
> >     line 798, in 
> >         extract_button=Radiobutton(archivist_buttons,variable,text='Extract
> >     news from archive', value=1, font=('Times',24),command=extracts)
> >     File
> >     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py",
> >     line 2978, in **init**
> >         Widget.**init**(self, master, 'radiobutton', cnf, kw)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py",
> >     line 2284, in **init**
> >         cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py",
> >     line 106, in _cnfmerge
> >         for k, v in c.items(): AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'items'

Can someone explains the error and gives me a hand to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
extract_button=Radiobutton(archivist_buttons,variable,text='Extract news from archive', value=1, font=('Times',24),command=extracts)
```

You're assigning `variable` incorrectly, the `Radiobutton` is looking for `variable['items']` which doesn't exist because `StringVar()` doesn't have an attribute called `'items'`.

Instead you should assign your `StringVar()` as `variable=variable`. Meaning the full call would be:

```
extract_button=Radiobutton(archivist_buttons,variable=variable,text='Extract news from archive', value=1, font=('Times',24),command=extracts)
```